# Thread safe method without using any type of lock

Tags: c#

how we can create a thread safe method without using any type of lock?Any Help will be highly appericiated. thanks

Comment: A method that does nothing should be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need to do inside the method, however usually a technique called [CompareAndSwap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) can be used. The .NET framework uses the [CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange%28VS.71%29.aspx) function. In any case you have to check if you can express your lock in a way that is suitable for CAS.

Comment: Creating a ThreadSafe collection whose Add method is thread safe rest of the methods are not but i dnt have to use any type of lock

Comment: @ethicallogics And which threadsafe collection were you using? Some of them use explicit locking, and some use locking instructions such as CompareExchange.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid locking you also want to avoid shared (mutable) state. Functional programming is a paradigm where you don't have any mutable state. You can do functional style programming in many programming languages and environments, but to give an example, a language like Erlang is particular suited to solve these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very high-level question, so here a high-level answer:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify any shared state. i.e. for any piece of memory, there is at most one thread that can write to it. That's about your only choice if you want to avoid *all* locks.

Even "lockless" programming techniques (`Interlocked` class) use some kind of lock, even if it's a bit cheaper than normal locks.

Answer (score 1):

> how we can create a thread safe method without using any type of lock?

Either: do not mdify any shared state. Basically this means that either (a) you CAN make the method static without breaknig it (as it is not using any instance ariables) or (b) all these variables are read only AND READONLY (so another thead can not change them) OR you can deal with the change.

Alternative:

OR: you wake up and realize that funny ishes may not come true. The moment yuo modify shares state you neded "a kind of locking". There are lock free mchanisms for that, but they are "lock free" in the strict term ("no lock") not in your term (i.e. they use a KIND OF LOCK). Spinlocks technically are lock free - a spinlock is a kind of lock, but not a real lock.

Comment: yes there are many techniques like Monitor,InterLocked etc but all they directly or indirectly uses lock technique.

Comment: That basically is it. "Some kind of lock" ruels out every sensibel approach. How do I change the taste of food without using a kind of spice? Bad - veything you add for food purely for taste can be interpreted as being "some kind of spice" in this context.